# Windows 10: network ports seemingly busy but no process attached to the port

Tags: windows, networking, port

So, for a while now I've noticed that whenever I'm trying to run a local server or anything, even if I choose a random port number, it still appears to be busy. For example, I tried running MySQL on 3036 and the logs clearly said

```
2021-05-19 17:20:51 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-05-19 17:20:51 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

But here's the thing, I open netstat and check what process is using the port but there's nothing running on that particular port.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqKaW.png)

Comment: So you didn't configure it for port 3036 correctly. The error message confirms it. Off topic.

Comment: @user207421 No, i've attached the screenshot that clearly shows there's no process on that port. And this isn't just for MySQL I've had this problem with a lot of other applications as well.

Comment: You claimed you used the random port '3036', yet your `netstat` output proves that your actual configuration was for `3306`. Or was that just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with MySQL just now. The culprit was a `vEthernet (WSL)` ethernet device. After disabling it and rebooting, MySQL started again normally.

Comment: 'Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #6' for some reason released one of the ports that gave access rights problems. But I had to disable/enable my Ethernet in Device manager to make all the others work as well. Of course the number #6 is meaningless for other installs.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is, in Device Manager, removing Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter (all of them), and then 'Disable device' on the physical network devices (e.g. ethernet and WiFi). After that it worked fine again, even with the physical network devices enabled again.